# Android basic calculator

Tags: android, calculator

I am trying to build a basic calculator. The code is fine (I guess). I get no error at run time, eclipse successfully compiles it. Pretty much everything fine BUT when I enter numbers in the editText view then try to do some calculation by clicking on the "calculate" button the application crashes.Here is the code that crashes the application:

```
    private OnClickListener calcListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String f = first.getText().toString();
            String s = second.getText().toString();
            float fValue = Float.valueOf(f);
            float sValue = Float.valueOf(s);
            if((f.length() == 0) || (s.length() == 0))
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter data in the first section", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else{   
                switch(sign.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
                {
                case R.id.mult:
                    float res_Mult = fValue*sValue;
                    result.setText(String.valueOf(res_Mult));
                case R.id.plus:
                    float res_Add = fValue*sValue;
                    result.setText(String.valueOf(res_Add));
                case R.id.minus:
                    float res_Minus = fValue*sValue;
                    result.setText(String.valueOf(res_Minus));
                case R.id.div :
                    float res_Div = fValue*sValue;
                    result.setText(String.valueOf(res_Div));
                }// end switch
            }// end else
        }
    };// end onclik

    Listener
```

The problem seems to be the calculation since I tried to output "Hello" on the textview that is supposed to display the results of the calculations once the button "calculate" is clicked and it worked.

```
Button calc = null;
    EditText first = null;
    EditText second = null;
    RadioGroup sign = null;
    TextView result = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //binding 
        calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);// the "calculate" button
        first = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first); //the first EditText
        second = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.second);//the second EditText
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);// The textView that this supposed to display the result.

        //setting listeners
        calc.setOnClickListener(calcListener);
        first.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
        second.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    }

    private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            result.setText(" ");
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };// end textWatcher
```

Here is the logCat:

```
    08-29 19:18:29.323: D/dalvikvm(1951): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
    08-29 19:18:31.593: D/dalvikvm(1951): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 72K, 10% free 2892K/3192K, paused 108ms, total 111ms
    08-29 19:18:32.183: D/libEGL(1951): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
    08-29 19:18:32.213: D/(1951): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8cfd430, tid 1951
    08-29 19:18:32.223: D/libEGL(1951): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
    08-29 19:18:32.233: D/libEGL(1951): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
    08-29 19:18:32.313: W/EGL_emulation(1951): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    08-29 19:18:32.323: D/OpenGLRenderer(1951): Enabling debug mode 0
    08-29 19:18:50.674: D/AndroidRuntime(1951): Shutting down VM
    08-29 19:18:50.674: W/dalvikvm(1951): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0eb8648)
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951): java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at com.example.gets.calculator.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:76)
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    08-29 19:18:50.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post more code and the stack trace (crash log)

Comment: On line 76 there is a Toast.makeText inside an if statement.

Comment: Are you aware that you do not have any `break` statements in any of the cases you are switching on? This will cause each case to fall-through to all the cases below it. Was that your intention?

Comment: Thank you @ChristopherPerry that was the problem. It's working fine now.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry how do I accept it?

Comment: Select the check mark on the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch statement has no breaks. That's a bug, it will cause each case to fall through to the next case and execute every piece of code in all of the cases below it.

```
    switch(sign.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
      case R.id.mult:
        float res_Mult = fValue*sValue;
        result.setText(String.valueOf(res_Mult));
      case R.id.plus:
        float res_Add = fValue*sValue;
        result.setText(String.valueOf(res_Add));
      case R.id.minus:
        float res_Minus = fValue*sValue;
        result.setText(String.valueOf(res_Minus));
      case R.id.div :
        float res_Div = fValue*sValue;
        result.setText(String.valueOf(res_Div));
    }// end switch
```